# Formula to format minutes value into "N hours, M minutes" string

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm referring to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1305614/microsoft-excel-conditional-number-formatting) respectively to [this **edited** answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1305614/microsoft-excel-conditional-number-formatting/1305651#1305651). There is a column with time periods in minutes. The time period of three hours and two minutes would be `182`. How to conditionally format the cells using a formula to get the following results?

`0` → `0 minutes`

`1` → `1 minute`

`2` → `2 minutes`

`60` → `1 hour`

`120` → `2 hours`

`181` → `3 hours, 1 minute`

`63` → `1 hour, 3 minutes`

Do I need to do some (rounded) division and some modulo calculation? Or is there a built-in function for things like that?

Comment: Excel stores dates *(and times)* as "serial numbers", where the fractional part of the serial number represents a fraction of a day.  Formatting that fraction properly can express it as hours and minutes. So... just divide all your numbers by (24*60), the number of minutes in a day.  That will convert them into a fraction of a day.  Then format them as a time, ab

Comment: Excel stores dates *(and times)* as "serial numbers", where the fractional part of the number is a fraction of a day. So... just divide all your minutes by (24*60), the number of minutes in a day.  That will convert them into fractions of a day. Then format the numbers as times using formats similar to the ones suggested in answers to your previous question.  Excel will do all the hard work for you, hopefully.

Comment: @Bandersnatch - I believe Ben added this question based on my suggestion to consider whether these values should be stored as durations or times (depending on the use case).

Comment: I presume the last entry is a typo: should be **3 hours**, not 1 hour.

Comment: It should be `1 hour, 3 minutes`. I fixed that. Thank you!

Comment: Correction: It should be `63`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=IF(A1=0,"0 minutes",IF(A1>=60,FLOOR(A1/60,1) & " hour" & IF(A1>=120,"s",""),"") & IF(MOD(A1,60)>0,IF(A1>=60,", ","") & MOD(A1,60) & " minute" & IF(MOD(A1,60)>1,"s",""),""))`

According to the comments you are using German Excel, which uses semi-colons to separate function parameters, so replace the commas with semi-colons:

`=IF(A1=0;"0 minutes";IF(A1>=60;FLOOR(A1/60;1) & " hour" & IF(A1>=120;"s";"");"") & IF(MOD(A1;60)>0;IF(A1>=60;", ";"") & MOD(A1;60) & " minute" & IF(MOD(A1;60)>1;"s";"");""))`

(Note: there is still one comma in there because that is in the output string.)

```
0      0 minutes
1      1 minute
2      2 minutes
59     59 minutes
60     1 hour
61     1 hour, 1 minute
62     1 hour, 2 minutes
119    1 hour, 59 minutes
120    2 hours
121    2 hours, 1 minute
122    2 hours, 2 minutes
179    2 hours, 59 minutes
180    3 hours
181    3 hours, 1 minute
182    3 hours, 2 minutes
1439   23 hours, 59 minutes
1440   24 hours
```

Comment: Microsoft Excel: "There is a problem with this formula."

Comment: After it shows the error, it should highlight the position in the formula where parsing failed - where is that? FYI I pasted it back into Excel and it worked fine. The problem may have been because I referenced cell `A17` for no apparent reason (I just happened to copy it from row 17 originally). I've changed it to reference cell `A1` so you can paste it into the first row. Obviously you'd need to fix the reference if your data is not in that column.

Comment: Of course I modified the cell references to fit at first. Microsoft Excel: "Mit dieser Formel gibt es ein Problem. Sie möchten gar keine Formel eingeben? Wenn das erste Zeichen ein Gleichheitszeichen (=) oder Minuszeichen (-) ist, hält Excel Ihre Eingabe für eine Formel: Sie geben "=1+1" ein, und die Zelle zeigt: "2" an. Um dieses Problem zu vermeiden, geben Sie zuerst ein Apostroph (') ein: Sie geben "=1+1" ein, und die Zelle zeigt "=1+1" an."

Comment: Translation: "There is a problem with this formula. You do not want to enter a formula? If the first character is an equals sign (=) or minus sign (-), Excel considers your input to be a formula: you enter "= 1 + 1" and the cell displays "2". To avoid this problem, first enter an apostrophe ('): enter "= 1 + 1" and the cell will display "= 1 + 1"."

Comment: @Ben - yeah that's Excel's generic error message for a formula parsing problem. When that error is displayed, it will also highlight some part of the formula in the formula bar. Can you see where it is highlighted?

Comment: A, I see. Excel highlights `0,"0`.

Comment: @Ben - After you mentioned the German error message, I had a suspicion that it didn't like the comma after the 0 since that is a decimal separator in European Excel. So I did some Googling and discovered in German Excel you use semi-colon to separate parameters of formulae. I will update the question to show the German version. In future, you may need to mention this in questions :).

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Actually even the keywords respectively the function names (`IF`, `FLOOR`, `MOD`) have to be in German. With this formula it works like a charm: `=WENN(A1=0;"0 Minuten";WENN(A1>=60;ABRUNDEN(A1/60;1) & " Stunde" & WENN(A1>=120;"n";"");"") & WENN(REST(A1;60)>0;WENN(A1>=60;", ";"") & REST(A1;60) & " Minute" & WENN(REST(A1;60)>1;"n";"");""))` Thank you very much!

Comment: There is one question left: Is it possible to put the formula into the same column as where the data reside? That would get me a clean table.

Comment: @Ben - if the data is just a number then no, you can't apply the formula in the same cell. If the data itself is a formula, then yes you could combine the two formulae.

Comment: Is there any workaround to end up with only one column? (By the way, when I start with `@andrew` it automatically gets truncated when adding the comment. How do you keep `@Ben`?)

Comment: @Ben - how do you populate the table? By typing in values? Or do they get populated with VBA or a data connection? Are they in a named range? I ask because there is a somewhat fudgey way that might do the trick using VBA change event and a set of custom formats but whether it works may depend on how the data is populated.

Comment: The table is populated by just typing in the values.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your data is in column A. Write this formula in C2 and fill it down to translate minutes to fractional days (which is how Excel stores times):

```
=A2/1440
```

**Note**, *As you can find above in comments also, that to convert decimal minutes to time format, you can apply this formula `24*60` which gives `1440`.*

With the minutes converted to the form in which Excel handles time, you can simply use custom time formatting to display it.  Select the data range and apply this cell format:

```
h "hours, " m "minutes"
```

Note that Excel will treat times as hours only to the extent that they are less than a whole day, so this will work as long as your times are no more than 24 hours.

**Or,** you can use the HOUR and MINUTE functions to extract the components of the time.  In D2 you can use:

```
=HOUR(C2)&" hours, "&MINUTE(C2)&" minutes "
```

You get,

[image]

Again, this is limited to the portion of your time that is less than a day.  If you can have times more than a day, add the day count:

```
=INT(C2)&" days, "&HOUR(C2)&" hours, "&MINUTE(C2)&" minutes "
```

Now you get,

[image]

Comment: I'm not following why you want INT(C2) in the last formula.   That would concatenate an unlabelled day count to the hours, including a leading zero if the minutes value is under 1440.  If minutes are over 1440, you would get a confusing day count prefix plus any remaining hours less than 24 (e.g., 25 hours would display as 11 hours).  Without INT, it displays only the portion of minutes less than full days.  Add 1500 to your example to see how it displays.

Comment: @fixer1234, if not use INT then from 1 to 183 excel produces full lenght values like for 1 is 0.0006944444444444440 hours.

Comment: If you remove "INT(C2)&" from the formula, you'll see that isn't the case.  Also, simply formatting, like the first solution, only works for times less than a day.  Suggestion: remove the INT function since that just causes an error, and just add a caveat that the formulas work for times less than one day.  The OP may not have times longer than that, in which case, either will solve the problem.

Comment: I've got your point. Others is If I add =If(INT(A2)>0, INT(A2)&"Day(s),,,. Then for 1500 it gives 1 Day(s) 1 hour.

Comment: @fixer1234, thanks you have raised useful points,, now I've included screen shot will help readers to work with 24 Hrs data :-) . Have Nice weekend.